# PowerShell Script To Send An Incremental Number To Discord

Tags: powershell, discord

Good afternoon everyone,
Kind stuck here at the moment. What I am trying to achieve is using a powershell script send an incremental number to Discord. Eg;

> 2000 *[Return]*
>
> 2001 *[Return]*
>
> 2002 *[Return]*
>
> ... and so on

Any guidance is most welcome.

Cheers

Comment: Can you show us what youve tried so we can help troubleshoot the code?

Comment: Auto-increment is a very common thing in scripting/programming for decades. Not so Powershell specific thing. There are tons of examples/samples all over the web. Has bee for years. In most cases, it's nothing more than a simple loop. Sending to Discord, I don't use it, so, I've no idea what steps that would need. Yet the loop will give you the number, you can send.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment...

> "PowerShell auto-increment' https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22PowerShell+auto-increment%27&t=h_&ia=web

```
1..10 | 
ForEach {2000 + $PSitem}
# Results
<#
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
#>
```

Again, I know nothing about discord, but there is a PowerShell module for it.

```
Find-Module -Name '*discord*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Version Name                  Repository Description                              
------- ----                  ---------- -----------                              
0.2.2   PSDiscord             PSGallery  Simple module to send messages to Discord
2.0     RWTodd.DiscordianDate PSGallery  A Discordian Date cmdlet (Get-DDate) 
#>
```

See details from the author here:

> https://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/psdiscord-powershell-module

Answer (score 0):

The same code for getting the numbers as @postanote and for discord.
You can use the discord webhooks api. A guide on that is here:
https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2018/3/10/using-discord-webhooks-with-powershell

This should include all you need. without external modules.